# Django filter many to many fields on admin panel each time

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm a new Django learner and in my project I'm facing a massive database. I'm using many to many fields for Parts that can be used in several Models(models of Home Appliances) and every model has its own category so my code is kinda like this :

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    class Model(models.Model):
        model_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        model_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Part(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        used_models = models.ManyToManyField(Model)
```

so every time I want to add a Part I have choose between lots of Models .
there is `formfield_for_manytomany` but that will filter it for good and I want to filter every time I want to add a Part based on Models categories .
if there is a way I would be happy to learn it.